# PHP Soap authentication header

Tags: php, api, soap

Sample Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="https://ws.intermedia.net/Account/Management">

<soapenv:Header>
  <AuthentificationInfo>
     <login>[PLRAdminUserName]</login>
     <password>[PLRAdminPassword]</password>
     <accountID>[accountID]</accountID>
  </AuthentificationInfo>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <GetAccount>
     <accountID>[accountID]</accountID>
  </GetAccount>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

WSDL: https://controlpanel.msoutlookonline.net/WebServices/Account/AccountService.asmx?WSDL

PHP:

```
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

    $wsdl = "https://controlpanel.msoutlookonline.net/WebServices/Account/AccountService.asmx?WSDL";
    $ns = 'https://ws.intermedia.net/Account/Management';

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
        "trace" => 1,
        "exceptions" => 0
    ));

    $login = 'xxxx';
    $password = 'xxxx';
    $partnerID = 1234;
    $accountID = 12345678;

    $headerBody = array('AuthentificationInfo'=>array(
        'login' => $login,
        'password' => $password,
        'accountID' => $partnerID
    ));
    $header = new SoapHeader($ns, 'AuthentificationInfo', $headerBody);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
    $client->__soapCall("echoVoid", array(null));

    $value = $client->GetAccount($accountID);
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
soap:ServerServer was unable to process request. ---> Access denied; Code: 0x0008
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an incorrect namespace.

Also Mikaël DELSOL's answer helped as I didn't need the `array('AuthentificationInfo'=>` part.
Also didn't need: `$client->__soapCall("echoVoid", array(null));`

Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the incorrect name space?

Answer (score 5):

Try with

```
     $headerBody = array(
      'login' => $login,
      'password' => $password,
      'accountID' => $partnerID);
```

Comment: Then I would advise you to try to generate the abstraction layer package according to this WSDL on https://www.wsdltophp.com/, you'll see that it's really easier to call your web service than ever. You'll be able to easily set the Soapheader without any doubt and questionning. Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 2):

just for anyone else that may ever run across this:

I changed

```
$ns = 'https://ws.intermedia.net/Account/Management';
```

to:

```
$ns = 'http://schemas.msoutlookonline.net';
```